# What's the proper response when someone says something modest and underrated about himself

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Recently when I told a British colleague of mine that he sent me the right assets earlier he told me this:

> Wow, me being efficient? Doesn't sound right

I understand that this is supposed to be modesty in a funny way but I'm not sure how to respond to this. And so I choose an awkward silence instead. We have the same thing in the my own culture but translating the proper response there wouldn't make any sense in English. I know I can respond like this:

> Oh! You're being too modest

But I don't want to sound like I'm from 18th century. So what could be the proper response to this sentence?

Comment: For communicating verbally, in person, I suggest a [sensible chuckle](http://i.imgur.com/himZD0M.gif) rather than an awkward silence. It's a little joke, and you're both in on it, so it should be acknowledged. No additional response is required.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the proper response in your own culture?

Comment: Not relevant, but this [truth table about British politeness](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/10280244/Translation-table-explaining-the-truth-behind-British-politeness-becomes-internet-hit.html) might come in handy next time!

Comment: @MarkBannister In Iranian culture usually expressing disagreement with such statements is the polite thing to do. So for informal conversations one could say: "get out of here" (maybe not the exact sentence but something in the same emotional direction) and for a formal conversation: "I don't believe that for a second"

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Your solution makes the most sense to me, thanks!

Comment: @nOjan: Thanks - you *can* say something similar in English, but it could be open to misinterpretation (especially to someone you didn't know very well). Jasper's answer would probably be the best bet.

Comment: You can say, “Yeah. What’s with you lately?” in a warm jocular tone.

Comment: Extrapolating from the Truth Table in @BiscuitBoy's comment, above, this is what your British colleague was really saying:  "Of course I did it correctly, unlike you, you fumblefingered clod"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You're too modest

is a common response. It does not make you sound like you are from the eighteenth century.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you think you'd sound like you're from the 18th century. The word "modest" is still in common usage, as [this ngrams link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmodest%3B%2Cc0) shows.

Personally I'd be more inclined to word it as:

> Don't be so modest!

but your wording is fine.

---

*As an aside, and not really a language but a cultural aspect, if I knew the person well enough I'd be tempted to respond:*

> Yes, I was surprised too!

Comment: I also would prefer using "Don't be so modest". +1)